# How to get array json instead of object json

Tags: json, angular, api, service, format

I made some autocomplete feature, and it required some array method. I want to use array json as my API instead of object json.

Since filter method only works for array. I have to use array json[] as my API url, but my API is an object json{} file. How to make it as an array?
I tried with some array json API. The code works with array json, but it doesn't work with object json.

HTML:

```
         <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="getOptionText">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of (filteredOptions | async)" [value]="option">
            {{ option.make }}
          </mat-option>
         </mat-autocomplete>
```

Service ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  opts = [];

  getData() {
    return this.opts.length ?
      of(this.opts) :
      this.http.get<any>('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9').pipe(map(data => this.opts = data));
  }
}
```

Component ts:

```
  constructor(private service: Service) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.searchForm.controls['customerId'].valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(100),
      switchMap(value => value.length >= 3 ? this.doFilter(value) : [])
    );
  }

  doFilter(value) {
    return this.service.getData()
      .pipe(
        map(response => response.filter((option: { make: { toLowerCase: () => { indexOf: (arg0: any) => number; }; }; }) => {
          return option.make.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === 0;
        }))
      );
  }

  getOptionText(option) {
    return option.make;
  }
```

I expected API JSON is array or autocomplete feature works.

Answer (score 0):

In your Service try using: `from` instead `of`. Check this [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html).

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbaedp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) based on your code.